# How to merge different applications in to one application

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces

I have 3 applications, 1 is JSP and rest 2 are JSF-Primefaces applications. All are running on same server running on same server.

The versions used on 2 JSF applications are not same. One is using JSF2.1.13 & PF3.5 and another is JSF2.2.0&PF5.2.

I have a requirement to include one of the JSF(using JSF2.2&PF5.2) applications in to another 2 applications one JSP and another is JSF(using JSF2.1.13 & PF3.5).

The JSF application should be included in such a way that it has to act like its part of application to which its included. i.e, when i click on an menu in JSP it should open the included JSF application so that user feels like he has opened just another page of JSP.

How can I achieve this?
How do I take care of Data exchanging between the applications?

Comment: Are you aware that you can just deploy and run multiple WARs on one and same application server? The way how this question is formulated suggests you aren't.

Comment: What data exchange between applications should there be? The question suggests that integration is limited to links. Single sign on should work automatically, but each application will have its own sessions.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes i'm aware that I can deploy multiple application on same server. My question is can I include on in another like using `ui:include` or using `<%@ include %>` ?

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov: OK single sign on would be sufficient for my purpose. thanks.